# Vue: Setting Data by matching route query

Tags: vuejs2, computed-properties

I'm attempting to set data fields provided by an array based on the Vue Router query. For example, when someone lands on my website using `example.com/?location=texas`, I want to set the location data by an array.

An example the array:

```
locations {
    {
        slug: "texas",
        tagline: "Welcome to Texas",
    }, {
        slug: "california",
        tagline: "Welcome to California",
    }
}
```

I know this should be done using a computed property, however I am unable to get anything functioning. I've tried simple tests like `if (this.slug.location === "texas")`, and I cannot get the location data to populate. **I would also like to provide default data in case there are no route matches**.

Any help is extremely appreciated!

**Edit:**

I can accomplish this in a very manual way. Right now, I'm setting the query in data by the following:

```
slug: this.$route.query.location
```

I can display specific text by doing something like:

```
h3(v-if="slug === 'texas'") This will show for texas
h3(v-else-if="slug === 'california'") This will show for California
h3(v-else) This is default
```

The issue with this approach is there are various elements I need to customize depending on the slug. Is there any way I can create an array, and move whichever array matches a key in an array to the data??

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access a query param using the following ([link to Vue Router documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#route-object-properties)):

```
this.$route.query.location
```

So based on what you listed I would do something like...

```
export default {
  computed: {
    displayBasedOnLocationQueryParam() {
      switch(this.$route.query.location) {
        case 'texas':
          return 'Welcome to Texas'
        default:
          return 'hello there, generic person'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that I'm not using your array explicitly there. The switch statement can be the sole source of that logic, if need be.

Comment: This is great, however I need the data to be persistent and would ideally populate a dataset by matching to an array, or something like that. I've edited the original post for more detail.